# Pulldown for transistor + digital pullup?

Tags: esp8266

I'm just created this circuit:
[image: Circuit for motor control]

With this I first regulate the voltage from +12VDC down to +3.3 VDC [1), purple]. Then I have two parts:

Blue [2)]:
ESP01_01 controls transitor U4 which inverts the signal from GPIO2 (=J3 pin 2) and GPIO0 (=J3 pin 3) and U5 toggles the L296 motor driver power supply. This inverting is necessary because GPIO2 and GPIO0 need to be HIGH while booting. Also the signals from ESP01_01 (GPIO2, GPIO0) are used to send a signal to the motor driver for controlling the rotation direction of the motor. This signal is inverted by Q1 and Q2.
All this works properly - my question is: **Do I need to set a pulldown resistor for Q1 and Q2 to have LOW signal by default?** The collectors are not connected to anything because I didn't find a L296 for fritzing.

The third part, light blue [3)] is not mounted yet. This is a second ESP8266 (ESP01_02) which receives signals from two reed-switches (S1, S2). Since GPIO2 and GPIO0 need to be HIGH while booting I thought I use a pullup resistor for each switch - my question is: **Can I substitute these resistors by setting the GPIOs as INPUT_PULLUP?**

If something is wrong with this circuit, please let me know - I'm very new to electronics and so I'm glad to get improvement suggestions!

Comment: You must consider the rise time of cct C and pull-up internal R is not fast enough for analog signals to control deadtime. So yes you need a pull down <<1us

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75: To be honest I don't understand `cct C` and `<<1us`...  I guess that relates to question 1, right? How big should the pull down be? Also 4.7 kOhm?

Comment: Normally 30 pF is used when you don't know the driver ,PCB and CMOS input listed in the datasheet so they use this for standard rise times so 4k7*30pF = 148 ns which is good enough, but crossover commutation must turn off fast than turn on to create a dead-time, so that may not be adequate and requires further understanding how this fits together. In any case the L296 is obsolete unless used on large voltage motors due to the BJT voltage drop. so use a FET bridge IC instead